# cant use base64 image from css in img tag

Tags: html, css

I couldn't figure out Why below page doesn't show image when define **id** to get image data from css where it shows image when I give data directly in **src** attribute of **img** tag.

**img.html**

```
<html>
<head><title>img.css</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="img.css">
</head>
<body>
<img id="t"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

**img.css**

```
#t { background-image: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,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"); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you haven't provided a width and height for the image. HTML elements never resize themselves to fit the size of the background image, so you'll have to do that yourself.

And you have markup errors in the source: first of all, an `img` MUST have a `src` attribute. And `img` elements don't have end tags. So it's best to use another element, perhaps a `div` or a `span` with the proper styling.

```css
#t {
    width:100px; height:77px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAyADIAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj/wgARCABNAGQDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAGQABAQADAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcDBAUB/8QAFQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAH/2gAMAwEAAhADEAAAAaoAAAAAAAAAAA526ZAAJxR+cRVXkshV4SFXhDdGteHFq+PbsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/8QAIBAAAQQCAgMBAAAAAAAAAAAABAACAwUVFgZQEBITIP/aAAgBAQABBQLryzYA1HIyVn45RZlAk7DZLYbJbDZLYbJbDZLYbJHWRRzRiZhn13JSvaCT6xeCQhinYivWIr1iK9YivWIr1iK9XVC2doXFh40MNCM3tv/EABQRAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFD/2gAIAQMBAT8BD//EABQRAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFD/2gAIAQIBAT8BD//EACsQAAEDAAcGBwAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAgMEERIzNJGSFCEiMVBiBRAgQUJRcv/aAAgBAQAGPwLp7NpksB5qBKtRua9p92mv0wto0lkObWeEFX40BX40BX40BX40BX40BX40BNbSZLQbvHCArVHlfGe0oRzQbR+BU5B5jfHX8X8/MOpELJCNwrWEiyWEiyWEiyWEiyWEiyWEiyULfD4YozXxO5IGlSOlP0NwVmjxMjHaOr//xAAjEAACAQMDBAMAAAAAAAAAAAABEQAhwfBRcYEQIDFQYaGx/9oACAEBAAE/IfXmlDAQp2gh45KDz2hzHQGofyJndpndpndpndpndpndoN0bQQPAnDoR76w16mjccCh+oY0AeAAN+oxJsFod8IQhCDgK1kSmAz/X8nDwR76+3//aAAwDAQACAAMAAAAQ888888888884888CCCaF888888888888888//8QAGBEAAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAERMED/2gAIAQMBAT8Q2RUVFRVw/wD/xAAUEQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQ/9oACAECAQE/EA//xAAhEAEBAAAFBQEBAAAAAAAAAAABEQAhMWFxIFBRgZEQQf/aAAgBAQABPxDt9pNIGAUUH+tWGMwaBHCDHppP6gBlqTLr169evXrfX0aAR0LjyQhUbBoNm4P5kyt1B4A5Yrc167hQ+/udySdSw99d73ve4iurRSllXO6DiQ/zflKN8jwx5LQCty1W7e7/AP/Z"); }
```

```html
<div id="t"></div>
```

(Note that I took the size 100×77 from the size of the background image itself; you may have different requirements, so adjust as you need.)

---

However, you may feel that an `img` is the proper element here, because the picture is part of the document rather than just decoration. In that case, you have the option of putting the content in the `src` attribute. Then you won't have to set the width and height manually.

```html
<img id="t" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="&rarr;">
```

(Of course this solution is not as efficient in cases where you need the image more than once in the document.)